# Ember.js Application not rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I'm just starting out with Ember.js and I'm attempting to use it to render a fairly simple modal application.

Code is here https://gist.github.com/jhogendorn/5076997

I'm finding that there are no errors, however it is not rendering the application. What am I doing incorrectly? I'm using EmberJS 1.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ember rc1 your code cannot work, because you are trying to use the old router API. Have a look at the guides of Ember. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/
The API looks very different now. I guess it does not work, because you are overwriting the default router with your subclass, that does not use the new API. 
You can also have a look at this tutorial: http://twbrandt.github.com/2013/02/11/Ember-Quick_Start_Guide/
It shows a very basic example and i have seen it getting recommended very often.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not rendering is due to the $(document).ready(function() {...}); you have. Ember needs to fire up before the document loads. Take your ember app out of the $(document).ready function and it should render.

Beyond that, as pointed out earlier, you should use the [new router API](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) if you are using rc1.